# Is there a way to create a reverse connection without using SSH?

Tags: networking, reverse-tunnel

I have a device I would like to make connections to the outside world from, that only accepts incoming connections.

What I have right now is:

```
ssh -ND 8000 user@localmachine &
ssh user@remotemachine -NR 8901:localhost:8000
```

Now, it just so happens that the second ssh is doing a lot of unnecessary work. I'm on an incredibly secure network (read, a USB cable), and have no need for any kind of encryption. remotemachine is also very CPU-constrained.

Is there any other command I could use to create a reverse tunnel, that runs as fast as possible? It doesn't have to be a general solution, all I'll ever want to do is forward that internal port to my socks proxy.

Comment: First what version of USB are you using on both ends? (1.0,1.1,2.0, or 3.0) 1.x is 1mb/s.  Using 2.0 gets you 20mb/s-to 30mb/s and finally 3.0 takes you over 300mb/s.  Assuming USB 3.0 is to new for both computers gigabit nic to gigabit NIC is **"as fast as possible"**

Comment: Using iptables port forwarding sounds like a much better idea.  iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.4  --dports 8000  (something like this)

Comment: What OS the is on the source/target?  You could build a simple ip tunnel. http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.tunnel.ip-ip.html

Comment: @cybernard I'm using USB2.0 I'm also unsure of how splicing two new boxes in the middle of an existing connection could make it any faster. Unfortunately that iptables command will not work, because the device cannot create any outgoing connections.

Comment: @Zoredache localhost is running linux, and remotemachine is running iOS, a BSD-like.